# What is the best way to convert date from JavaScript string in format YYYYMMDD to JavaScript date? 

Tags: javascript, date

What is best way to convert date from JavaScript string in format YYYYMMDD to JavaScript date format.

```
var from_date = document.getElementById('from_date').value;             
var YYYY = from_date.substring(0,4);
var MM = from_date.substring(4,7);
var DD = from_date.substring(7,8);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var myDate = new Date( parseInt(YYYY,10), parseInt(MM,10)-1, parseInt(DD,10) );`

note that the month provided to the date constructor is actual month number - 1.

edits: ok, there are some issues with your date part extraction- `substring` is probably the most awkward of javascript's sub-stringing methods (`sub,substr,substring`). And after testing I stand by the month value having to be 1 less than the actual number. Here is a fixed sample.

```
var from_date = "20101127"; //document.getElementById('from_date').value; 
var YYYY = from_date.substring(0, 4);
var MM = from_date.substring(4, 6);
var DD = from_date.substring(6);
var myDate = new Date(parseInt(YYYY, 10), parseInt(MM, 10) - 1, parseInt(DD, 10)); 
alert(myDate); // should be november 27th 2010
```

Comment: I thought for sure you had to -1 the month as well, but in my testing that turned out to be untrue!

Comment: that's how it works in IE8 (all I have to test with at the moment). `alert( new Date(79,5,24) )` says June 24 1979.

Comment: Man, I don't know what the hell is wrong with Google Chrome but it was giving seriously inconsistent results.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, I struggled with the same question but came up with an easier way.
Create a hidden div tag and set the date into an attribute. then retrieve the attribute and use the sub string method to get something like Mar 01.

```
     <div id="test" style="display:none;" date=""></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var date = new Date();
     document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('date',date);
     var getdate = document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('date');
     var newdate = getdate.substr(4,7);
     alert(newdate);
     </script>
```

That's all thanks!
check out my operating system: hypertos(dot)webege(dot)com