# Convert date string of format `YYYYMMDD` into `DD/MM/YYYY`

Tags: javascript, string, date

I have an xml that gives me the date as a text in reverse "20200528". I need to change that string in a date format DD/MM/YYYY in JavaScript.

Comment: I have very minimal knowlodge of JavaScript and everything i searched are change YYYY/MM/DD to DD/MM/YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY. I have no idea where to start. I would like to see where are the similar question to mine, maybe i couldnt find them.

Comment: @AlexE. I think this is exactly what you're looking for  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3832031

Comment: There is no need for a Date object, just cut the string into parts using [*substring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or similar, then re–order and reformat the parts, e.g. `'20200528'.match(/^\d{4}|\d{2}/g).reverse().join('/')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible ways to process the pattern `YYYYMMDD` (4-digit year, 2-digit month, 2-digit day) is using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

- use [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to match groups of digits of necessary length (`(\d{n})`)
- [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) array of matches (skipping first item that holds the entire string) into variables `yyyy`, `mm`,`dd`
- build up the desired output, using [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Following is a quick demo:

```js
const dateStr = '20200528',
      [,yyyy,mm,dd] = dateStr.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/),
      
      result = `${dd}/${mm}/${yyyy}`
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```